# adding object to an array object in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm new to PHP. I've created an array $store

```
$store = array(
                'storeId'=> $shoe->storeId,
                'store'=> $shoe->store,
                'showAll'=> false,
                'shoes'=> new \stdClass
                );
```

I'm trying to add an object $shoe to 'shoes'. I did this

```
$store["shoes"]= $shoe;// This successfully adds $shoe object into $store
```

But i'm unable to append new objects to it. I want a result like this.

```
$store = array(
            'storeId'=> $shoe->storeId,
            'store'=> $shoe->store,
            'showAll'=> false,
            'shoes'=> {{$shoe1}, {$shoe2}...}
            );
```

**EDIT:**

```
foreach($product->shoes as $shoe) {
  $store = searchForId($shoe->storeId, $stores);// returns True if key present
  if($store === null){
    $store = array(
                    'storeId'=> $shoe->storeId,
                    'store'=> $shoe->store,
                    'showAll'=> false,
                    'shoes'=> []
                );
            $store['shoes'][] = json_decode(json_encode($shoe), true);
            array_push($stores, $store);
            }
            else{
                $store['shoes'][] = json_decode(json_encode($shoe), true);

            }
}
```

Comment: Your `shoes` index wants to be an array surely. Then you can add to it e.g. `$store['shoes'][] = new \stdClass;` for example?

Comment: I tried assigning it as `$store['shoes'][] = $shoe` but get an error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Yeah, because `'shoes'=> new \stdClass` should probably be `'shoes'=> []`, which is what I meant by the first bit of my comment :)

Comment: I made it an array and tried it now it gives me `Cannot use a scalar value as an array ` as error

Comment: There is no thing like an *"array object"* in PHP. [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) are different things. And there is the [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class. Its instances are objects (and not arrays) but can be used in expressions the same way the arrays are used.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your array like this:

```
$store = array(
    'storeId'=> $shoe->storeId,
    'store'=> $shoe->store,
    'showAll'=> false,
    'shoes'=> [],
);
```

Now `$store['shoes']` is an *array* instead of an *stdObject*.

This means that you can add to `$store['shoes']` like this:

```
$store['shoes'][] = $shoe;
```

---

Edit: Your variable is currently a stdClass object. I recommend converting this to an array since the rest of your data is stored as an array. You can do this easily like below:

```
$store['shoes'][] = json_decode(json_encode($shoe), true);
```

This works by encoding your object to a json string, and then decoding it to an array.

You can learn more about [`json_encode()` here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode()` here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: I made it an array and tried it now it gives me `Cannot use a scalar value as an array ` as error

Comment: @nash63 What does `$shoe` equal?

Comment: a complex object. `{_id:177618672, title:Adidas, description: ...}`

Comment: @nash63 I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you show me the output of `print_r($shoe)`?

Comment: stdClass Object ( [_id] => 5a72d285247e116ebda43053 [title] => Adidas Prophere [description] => Testing the limits of street style, adidas unveil their Prophere - a new chunky soled sneaker inspired by global fashion.

Comment: I still get the same error `Cannot use a scalar value as an array as error` :(

Comment: @nash63 I cannot reproduce. The code above works for me. Did you declare your array as I said above?

Comment: @nash63 I'm not sure. As I said the code above works for me, I can't reproduce your error. Maybe time for a new question regarding this new problem?

Comment: I just added more info with my code. can you please check it out

Comment: @nash63 The code looks okay to me, but I've never really worked with stdClasses. I suggest asking a new question, be sure to include your error message and all other related details.